# Per App VPN functionality in android below lollipop version

Tags: android, vpn

I want to allow some specific applications(by default all) to pass through vpn.

It is a default API in `lollipop` version but I want to implement in below lollipop version.

How can i implement this? Please help me if someone has any idea.

Comment: Could you provide some details as to what your current implementation looks like? I.e. what specific Lollipop API are you referring to? What is missing on older platforms? etc

Comment: I want to bypass some selected app through vpn and other as normal i use.
I want to send allowed application network data to my server.
Please read  this function in android document: addAllowedApplication(String packageName)

Answer (score 1):

you could have a look at [shadowsocks-android](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-android/) , it provides a feature you described: VPN works on global or specific apps.

although this project mainly use Scala, there are similar name apis on Android.

may it help.

Comment: Have you tested this app? How can i check that this is bypassing specific app through vpn?

Comment: Its description on play store says: "All features including per-App VPN work on Android 5.0 without ROOT permission".
Means, This feature will work on lollipop version because 5.0 is also lollipop.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it will not work on below lollipop version. I have read .scala file which is creating vpn service. It is checking os version to perform per app vpn functionality.

Comment: oh,it does. it seems you'd better filter coming applications if there is a way to identify it.

Comment: another potential way is to identify each sockets port with os process-port table

Comment: No, I am not able to find way to resolve this. This is a permission set at kernel level, I think. So to support below lollipop I'll have to look into jni level. I have already searched for jni level but i am not able to find any solution. There are many application related to firewall they are also doing using jni level code. But i need some help at jni level.

Comment: Can be detect that currently which process is generating ip packets? I mean uid of app which is generating packets.

Comment: os process-port table, For this we need root device. Because all rules are defined at iptables.

Comment: emmm,problem turn to set a firewall instead of VPN. Here is a open source project [afwall](https://github.com/ukanth/afwall) . But it need permission SuperUser, but I think it also change iptable with su. Another reference is [droidwall](https://code.google.com/p/droidwall/).

Comment: both project you mentioned need root permission :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74089/discussion-between-dharmendra-and-saki-m).